# How do I convert a curl GET request to a Zapier Webhook request?

Tags: curl, zapier

I'm trying to use Zapier to query a table in AirTable.

Airtable's api docs give examples for curl, and this one works fine:

curl https://api.airtable.com/v0/myappidxyz/Sheet%20Name -H "Authorization: Bearer keymyapikeyasdlkfjsl"

It returns the rows of data in the sheet.

But when I try to do the same thing in Zapier, I get a 404 error:

We had trouble sending your test through.
The app returned "Could not find table Digital Weekly Reports in application myappidxyz". This usually happens when a field value used in this step is missing or we're unable to find some information in your connected app or service. Make sure that the information exists and that the field values used in this step are entered correctly.

This is my Zapier config.  Note, I think it's authenticating correctly, because if I change any aspect of the auth in the headers section I get an authentication error.

[Zapier Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLgHc.png)

Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team. Great question!

Airtable handles request from Zapier a little differently than normal API requests. If you can, we recommend using the official Zapier app, since we take care of all that for you. If you don't do that, you've got two options:

- Change the `User-Agent` header to be something else ([example](https://zappy.zapier.com/6D866E99-5664-4CBB-89AF-5722D0A9C5EE.png))
- Instead of using the table name, use the table id instead of the name (as found in the url when viewing the table on the web). In the following: `https://airtable.com/tblabc123/viwdef456?blocks=hide`, you'd grab `tblabc123`. So your request url would be `https://api.airtable.com/v0/myappidxyz/tblabc123`

I tested both of the above and either will work.

Comment: Hi David,
Unfortunately we can't use the official Zapier app because it doesn't implement the API - just two use cases: new row, and new view in row.  I'm trying to retrieve lots of rows, batched, not new.

This works though - thank you!